# How to add a UsernameToken to the RequestSoapContext property of web service proxy class

Tags: .net, wcf, webservice-client

I have a service that I have referenced which creates a proxy class "MyWebService". However when I use that class its object doesnt seem to have the RequestSoapContext property.
Here below is how I was expecting to consume the service:

```
            MyWebService objWS = new MyWebService();
            UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken("User","Password", PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
            objWS.RequestSoapContext.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 60;
            objWS.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);
            objWS.RequestSoapContext.Security.MustUnderstand = false;
```

Is there some configuration/modification that I need to make to the generated proxy class so that I can get the RequestSoapContext in there proxy class or do I need to do something on service side?

Thanks for your time...

Comment: Inported as WebReference or ServiceReference? What kind of Authentication is at the other end?

Comment: imported as WebReference. Its a third party service so I dont know what they have done there.. still in the process of finding out.

Answer (score 6):

After referencing your webreference, click web reference at solution explorer to find reference.cs file. If you find it, open that file. You can see your web service class is dervied from `System.Web.Services.xxxx`. Change that to

public partial class MyWebService: **Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol**

Comment: Shouldn't he just add the dll and then update his service configuration?  I will respond with a full answer in a second.